# How to prevent from opening window on no confirmation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have href which when clicked should open up a popup modal. Now I need a confirm message to display before showing that modal window. I have used following code. My problem is when I click 'No', it still opens that window.

```
<a href="ajax/popup-add-user.php" id="btn-add-user">Add User</a>


$('#btn-add-user').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(confirm("Do you want to continue?"))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Your code looks good, What you exactly want.?

Comment: @ShyamShingadiya I want to open window only if yes button is pressed of  confirm(). Currently, it opens even i press 'No'

Comment: as per above code it seems like you need to add more code. Please share your code here.

Comment: In the code above you have prevented default, so no action will get performed irrespective of yes or no. you can do like `$('#btn-add-user').on('click', function(){ return confirm("Do you want to continue?"); });})` and yeah please try to post fiddle!

Comment: Show the code please where you open modal window, probably you just have to put that inside the else statement or call it as a function. but you can not have another listener on `$('#btn-add-user')`

Answer (score 0):

Try like so: Put your open modal code inside `openModal function`

```js
var openModal = function() {
    // put open modal window code here
    console.log('open modal window here');
};

$('#btn-add-user').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(confirm("Do you want to continue?")) {
        return openModal();
    } else {
        e.stopPropagation();  // also add this line
        console.log('do nothing');
        return false;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="ajax/popup-add-user.php" id="btn-add-user">Add User</a>
```